# Copying files from folders into one folder with file renaming

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I faced such problem.

I have a collection of books with the following folder and file structure:

```
/oldfolder/0000 Daniel Defoe - Robinson Crusoe/Daniel Defoe - Robinson Crusoe.fb2
/oldfolder/0001 Jules Verne - The Mysterious Island/Jules Verne - The Mysterious Island.fb2
/oldfolder/0002 Jules Verne - Twenty Thousand Leagues under the Sea/Jules Verne - Twenty Thousand Leagues under the Sea.fb2
/oldfolder/0003 Henry Freeman - Sumerians: A History From Beginning to End/Henry Freeman - Sumerians: A History From Beginning to End.fb2
/oldfolder/0004 Henry Freeman - War of 1812: A History From Beginning to End/Henry Freeman - War of 1812: A History From Beginning to End.fb2
```

I want to copy all files into one folder and add the first word (index number) of the parent directory to the file name:

```
/newfolder/0000 Daniel Defoe - Robinson Crusoe.fb2
/newfolder/0001 Jules Verne - The Mysterious Island.fb2
/newfolder/0002 Jules Verne - Twenty Thousand Leagues under the Sea.fb2
/newfolder/0003 Henry Freeman - Sumerians: A History From Beginning to End.fb2
/newfolder/0004 Henry Freeman - War of 1812: A History From Beginning to End.fb2
```

Unfortunately, I am not good at writing scripts - just learning.
I can to copy all files into one folder, the problem is adding the first word from the name of the parent folder.

I tried different options. For example:

```
find -name *.fb2 -execdir sh -c 'f={} d=$( pwd | awk -F / '{print $NF}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Do you have always only one book (fb2-file) in each folder? I would perhaps not run the `find` over the fb2-files, but over the folders.  If you don't have a deeply nested file structure at all, I would not use `find` at all, but loop over the directories `for dir in oldfolder/[0-9]*; do ...; done`. If you do this, you have the directory name, where you can extract your index number, and fiddle with the fb2-file in its subdirectory.

Comment: I have a genuine question about word usage: why do you use both "directory" and "folder" in this post?  A "directory" is an object in a file system; a "folder" is an artifact of a gui.  Why mix the two terms?

Comment: @William Pursell
I mean "directory"
Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @user1934428 
Thanks, I'll try using a "for" loop

Comment: @Sergey: If you get stuck with it, just ask a new question, and post the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
nd=newfolder; mkdir -p "$nd"; find . -name "*.fb2" -exec bash -c 'f="{}"; nf="${f##*/}"; i="${f%/*}"; i="${i##*/}"; i="${i%% *}"; mv -v "${f}" "'${nd}'/${i} ${nf}"' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do in case of an error, so I'm taking the safer approach and aborting if an operation fails or an unexpected file is found.  By using `ln` instead of copying or moving the data, the old directory remains untouched, so you can perform the action multiple times, removing the old directory tree only when done:

```
mkdir newdirectory && for d in oldfolder/*; do flag=0; 
    for f in "$d"/*; do 
        if test $((flag++)) -ne 0; then echo "Unexpected file found: '$f'" >&2; break 2; fi; 
        ln "$f" newdirectory/"${d#oldfolder/}".fb2 || break 2; done; done
```